# HTTP form POST method to server not sending email

Tags: objective-c, ios6, nsurlrequest

Im trying to send a data or what it seems to a form that is on the website, the action is `freecontactformprocess.php` and my code goes like this,

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.irabwah.com/freecontactformprocess.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

    NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Full_Name=%@&Email_Address=%@&Telephone_Number=%@&Your_Message=%@&AntiSpam=25",_fNameLabel.text, _emailLabel.text,_phoneLabel.text, _commentText.text];

    NSData *data = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setHTTPBody:data];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", [data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(conn){
         NSLog("Successfull!!");
     }
```

the purpose of this form is to send an email into my account which I integrated into the form on installation of this plugin, but the thing is I doesn't seems to get a the email when I run my test app, and when Im inputing values I don't include spaces yet.

The form looks like this,

[image]

Comment: Are the `NSURLConnection` delegate methods called? Do they report an error? If you have control of `freecontactformprocess.php` can you add logging statements to confirm you are receiving the data in the correct format?

Comment: Yep Im getting a response from the delegate methods of `NSURLConnection` and It doesn't give me an error, it gives a heck of an HTML code from 
`-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *responseStringWithEncoded = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: mutableData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response Data = %@", responseStringWithEncoded);
}`

Comment: Possibly silly question, but have you verified the form sends an email if you manually submit it? If that works, can you post the response text - the error might be buried in there.